# Is it possible for a 2nd-degree monomial to have 3 variables? (What about $6p^0qr$?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Is it possible for a 2nd-degree monomial to have 3 variables?

I think it's not, and then I remembered this: $6p^0qr$. But the $p^0$ is $1$, so for me it's not an example of a 2nd-degree monomial with three variables.

What do you think?

Comment: You are right. If the single term contains $3$ variables , the monomial must have at least degree $3$

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) gives coefficients used in multinomial expansions. In the case of, say, $(p+q+r)^2$, each *multinomial coefficient* is attached to a *term* $p^a q^b r^c$, where $a+b+c=2$ for non-negative integer $a$, $b$, $c$. Obviously, at least one of $a$, $b$, $c$ must be zero at any time, so zero-exponent factors are *recognized* and *embraced* by this formulation. Consequently, since a polynomial's terms are *monomials*, this makes the case that second-degree monomials *can* be considered to have three variables.

Comment: On the other hand, if you see $6qr$ out of context, and someone asks how many variables the monomial has, it's not-unreasonable to say "two: $q$ and $r$".

Comment: so does that mean it's possible for a monomial to have three variables and at the same time, it's in degree 2? or it depends on what context is being talked about? and for additional information, I just came across this question from my niece's homework. She studies Algebra I :).

Comment: @harpey1111: Many math textbooks (and, sadly, many math teachers) don't appreciate nuance. (Source: I was a math teacher who was frustrated by both textbooks and peers in this regard.) In order for us to provide an answer that best helps your niece, you should give the textbook's "official" definition of monomial.

Answer (score 1):

A monomial in 3 variables (say $x,y,z$) is of the form $cx^py^qz^r$ where $c$ is a nonzero constant and $p,q,r$ are positive integers (so each at least $1$).

The degree of the monomial is $p+q+r$, so it must be at least $3$. This makes degree $2$ impossible.

Note: this assumes the *minimal* variable list contains three variables; that is, all three variables contribute to the value of the monomial. In other words, there are *strictly* three variables. But this is no more problematic than stating that $x^2+0$ is not a binomial.

Answer (score -2):

A second degree monomial takes on the form of:

f(x) = ax^2

If you want the monomial to take on three variables then you could have:

f(x,y,z) = ax^2

Technically this would still be a function of three variables. Or you could have:

f(x,y,z) = a(xyz)^2

But I don't think this would be considered a polynomial anymore.

In your own example you have:

6p^oqr

Here p would be the variable and the oqr would have to be constants for the monomial to be degree 2. In other words:

oqr=2

Comment: so is it possible for a monomial in 2nd degree to have 3 variables?

Comment: This is just wrong. A monomial in 3 variables (say $x,y,z$) is of the form $cx^py^qz^r$ where $c$ is a nonzero constant and $p,q,r$ are positive integers (so each at least $1$). The degree of the monomial is $p+q+r$, so it must be at least $3$. This makes degree $2$ impossible.